# Eloquent BelongsToManyThrough

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
    User belongsToMany Project 

    Project belongsTo Account

   wanted: Account belongsToMany User Through Project
```

There's Subscription pivot model between projects and users.

I want:

```
$user->accounts
```

**Update:**

I imagine relationship that will get `$user->projects` then get `accounts`

```
$user->projects()->accounts()
```

Comment: $user->projects()->acounta()

Comment: $user->projects() return a collection of pivot table of project_user

Comment: can you share your table structure relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) if your structure allows:

```
class User extends Model
{
    ...

    public function accounts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Account',
            'App\Project',
        );
    }
```